# Publishing web map on website using PostGIS, GeoServer and OpenLayers

Tags: postgis, geoserver, openlayers, publishing, web-gis

I have been trying to create a web map using PostgreSQL/PostGIS - GeoServer - OpenLayers. However, the resulting map is on my localhost and the data published in GeoServer can be accessed solely through my own PC. Also, the link to my shapefiles/rasters possess the prefix of localhost:8081 (in the javascript code of the .html I have built).

How can I publish the web map I have created, on my own website so that everyone can visit the website and scroll around the map?

Comment: is your web site public? what web server are you using?

Comment: Yes, the website is public. I am a beginner in this field (especially web designing); therefore, I am not familiar with web servers and their relationships with Web GIS, however, I just know that the website that I would like to publish my web map on is based on LiteSpeed. Also, I can have access to another website created on the basis of Apache.

Comment: The classic way is to proxy your GeoServer (Tomcat/Jetty) server through a web server, such as Apache, then have your openlayers js + HTML as a web page, available through the same web server.  You'd need to change  the localhost:8081 to be the proxied geoserver address.

Comment: Thanks. The GeoServer can be proxied using the OGC Services, am I right?

Comment: No. geoserver provides the OGC services. The geoserver service is proxied through your webserver

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems you are done with *development*. Now it's time to take a step forward towards *[deploying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deployment_environment)* on the server. Then, if you are using a [VPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server), you need to install GeoServer on your server, so that it can be accessed through WWW.

**Note**: [OGC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Geospatial_Consortium) (Open Geospatial Consortium) is an organization that just regulates the standards and specifications for geospatial services, such as WMS, WFS, etc. GeoServer is a software that enables you to easily utilize geospatial services within your apps. So, WMS, WFS, WCS, etc., have nothing to do with the way your proxy server works.